# Gnome40: how to move window to specific non-primary monitor on another workspace?

Tags: gnome

I do recognise [How to move windows across displays in Gnome 3 with keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103819/how-to-move-windows-across-displays-in-gnome-3-with-keyboard) - but it does not address the following variation:

I regularly use both multiple monitors (l,c,r) and multiple workspaces (1,2). c is the primary monitor.

My observation is that whenever I move a window (on l1) to another workspace (2), it gets sent to the primary monitor (c2).

How can I send it straight from l1 to l2? or say from l1 to r2?

I am looking for keyboard shortcuts or even to a single drag&drop operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like using this keyboard combination?

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd> or <kbd>Page Down</kbd>