# How to mirror a screen in TigerVNC?

Tags: vnc, monitors

How to mirror a screen?

I have an answer (VNC).
A Linux *VNC server* - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download **TigerVNC** release
   (https://sourceforge.net/projects/tigervnc/files/stable/, code: https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/releases)
2. ```
   sudo cp -R [TigerVNC directory]/usr/* /usr/
   ...
   /usr/bin/vncpasswd
   ...
   /usr/bin/vncserver --help
   /usr/bin/vncserver
   ...
   ```
3. "Linux move window to desktop", "Linux move window to display" -  [Sharing an X server (session) across computers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/sharing-an-x-server-session-across-computers) , https://superuser.com/a/315865/1514321 , [How to move windows across displays in Gnome 3 with keyboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103819/how-to-move-windows-across-displays-in-gnome-3-with-keyboard)
   / [`export`] `DISPLAY=":1"; [app] --display=:1`
4. ```
   /usr/bin/vncserver -kill :1
   ```

**x11vnc**:
`sudo apt-get install`  *x11vnc*

```
x11vnc -usepw -display :0
...
[Ctrl-C]
```

x11vnc opts: `-find`, `-clip` ... `-opts` / `info x11vnc`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/30862/1427376